# How do you implement an enum in an object class - Java?

Tags: java, class, object, enums, constructor

This is my first time using enum in a class. I want to create a Pizza class so the user can create a Pizza object and then set the size, get the size, set the number of cheese etc.. `Pizza()` is the default constructor to initialize a Pizza object with no arguments. Thanks!!

```
package PizzaPackage;

public class Pizza {
private enum PizzaSize {
    small, medium, large }
protected int numcheese;
protected int numpep;
protected int numham;

Pizza(){
     PizzaSize newpizza= PizzaSize.medium; //Is this correct?
     numcheese = 1;
     numpep =0;
     numham=0;
}
public int getnumcheese() {
    return this.numcheese;

}

public int getnumpep() {
    return this.numpep;
}

public int getnumham() {
    return this.numham;
}

public void setSize(PizzaSize newpizza){
    //???

}
public PizzaSize getSize(){
    //???
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
Please read and follow the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite.

PizzaSize is an enum, and you have declared that properly.

However, you are mistakening that PizzaSize enum for an instance member that holds this value for any particular instance of a Pizza.

You should create an additional private member variable, called `private pizzaSize`, and your constructor should be doing

`this.pizzaSize = PizzaSize.medium;`

Then, in your `getSize()` method, you should be returning `this.pizzaSize;`

Additionally, your `setSize(PizzaSize newpizza)` should contain `this.pizzaSize = newpizza`

Answer (score 1):

Although you have created Enum, you forgot to have it as a instance member just like your other instance members `numcheese`, `numpep` etc.

```
PizzaSize newpizza;
```

Declare that as a member and use it.

```
package PizzaPackage;

public class Pizza {
private enum PizzaSize {
    small, medium, large }
protected int numcheese;
protected int numpep;
protected int numham;
PizzaSize newpizza;

Pizza(){
     newpizza= PizzaSize.medium; //Is this correct?
     numcheese = 1;
     numpep =0;
     numham=0;
}
public int getnumcheese() {
    return this.numcheese;

}

public int getnumpep() {
    return this.numpep;
}

public int getnumham() {
    return this.numham;
}

public void setSize(PizzaSize newpizza){
    this.PizzaSize newpizza = newpizza;

}
public PizzaSize getSize(){
    return newpizza;
}
}
```

---

> //Is this correct?

```
Pizza(){
     PizzaSize newpizza= PizzaSize.medium; //Is this correct?
     numcheese = 1;
     numpep =0;
     numham=0;
}
```

Not really. Because you are restricting the scope of your `PizzaSize` to this constructor only. That variable of type `PizzaSize` no more accessible outside of constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. change type of your `pizzasize` field to `PizzaSize`
2. use `ordinal` method of enum values: `pizzasize = newpizza.ordinal();` - it returns index of enum value in original enum.